# What happens if an airline reports a high number of involuntary denied boardings to the Department of Transportation?

Tags: usa, air-travel, airlines, denied-boarding, overbooking

I [read](https://www.paddleyourownkanoo.com/2024/03/25/delta-air-reportedly-bumped-42-people-on-a-massively-oversold-flight-to-tokyo-after-everyone-turned-up-for-the-flight/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20240325225742/https://www.paddleyourownkanoo.com/2024/03/25/delta-air-reportedly-bumped-42-people-on-a-massively-oversold-flight-to-tokyo-after-everyone-turned-up-for-the-flight/)):

> it’s in Delta’s interests to offer more in compensation for a voluntary bump rather than reporting higher involuntary denied boarding numbers to the Department of Transportation.

What happens if an airline reports a high number of involuntary denied boardings to the Department of Transportation?

Comment: This seems more like a question for Aviation.SE than Travel.SE.

Comment: Aviation.SE specifically excludes the "passenger aspects" of commercial air travel https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @GregHewgill That's about *being* a passenger on commercial aviation (visas, transits, all our bread & butter stuff).

Comment: @GregHewgill this question is not about "passenger aspects", it's about regulation and compliance